# Unable to decrypt RSA encrypted via the cryptography library in Python

Tags: python, java, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt some data in Python using RSA and the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library, then decrypt the data in a Java program. However whenever trying to decrypt the data in Java I get a `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException`. I am generating the key pair in Java using the following code

```java
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg;
        KeyPair kp;
        Key pub;
        Key priv;

        try {
            kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);

            kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

            pub = kp.getPublic();
            priv = kp.getPrivate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error generating key");
            return;
        }

        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

        String pubKeyStr = encoder.encodeToString(pub.getEncoded());
        String privKeyStr = encoder.encodeToString(priv.getEncoded());

        System.out.println("PUBLIC KEY: " + pubKeyStr + "\n");
        System.out.println("PRIVATE KEY: " + privKeyStr + "\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ciphertext: ");

        String b64ct = sc.nextLine();

        byte[] ct = decoder.decode(b64ct);
        byte[] decrypted;

        try {
            Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
            rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priv);

            decrypted = rsaCipher.doFinal(ct);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(new String(decrypted));
    }
}
```

I then copy the outputted public key and plug it into the following Python program

```py
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

pub = input('Enter public key: ')
pub_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + pub + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"

print('Public:\n', pub_key)
print()

pub_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(pub_key.encode("utf-8"))

message = b'super secret message'
ciphertext = pub_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
ciphertext = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)

print('Cipher:', ciphertext)
```

I then again copy the outputted ciphertext from this program and put it into the waiting input of the first Java program, then when the Java code tries to decrypt the ciphertext I get the exception.

Thanks

Comment: `String b64ct = sc.nextLine();` reads one line. Make sure you don't have line breaks in `ciphertext` after you encode it.

Comment: `sc.nextLine()` doesn't include the newline in the returned string

Comment: The Java RSA-instantiation "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding" has a SHA-256 hash and for the padding an SHA-1 hash, so simply change in your Python code "mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256())," to "mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),"

Comment: Ah that was it, thank you so much!